# Algorithm for minimum time to join lists

Tags: java, algorithm, join

So i came across this question and i am not sure about my solution to it.

here is the question (as i remember it):

lets define the time taken to join 2 lists as the length of list A plus the running time of list B.
for example: list A is 20, list B is 30, to join them would take 50ms.

given an unsorted array of integers, each representing a list size. return the minimum time to join all lists.

example: [20,30,10]

the sequence for minimum time to join all lists would be:
10+20 = 30
30+30 = 60 (30+30 because we are joining the previous joined lists to the next one)
so in total time is 90.

limitations are: time complexity of O(nlogn), space complexity of O(n).

My solution was to sort the array (nlogn) and the iterate on the array and connect smallest list with the next, that result was connected to the next smallest, etc. list join times were saved aside and summed at the end to return result.

I am pretty sure about my solution but i am unable to concretely show that there is no better solution.

Comment: `lets define the time taken to join 2 threads as the running time of thread A plus the running time of thread B. for example: thread A is 20ms, thread B is 30ms, to join them would take 50ms.` That's not a real-life definition.  If it were, nobody would use threads.

Comment: this be non-deterministic because the thread that does the `.join()` could be blocked by another thread ... or they could all be finished already and it happen immediately

Comment: How is that different from summing all the numbers?...

Comment: A tip: put "java" and "thread" on the same question and a lot of Java programmers will have an opinion that may or may not be related to the question itself.

Comment: like i said i remember this question from memory, I agree the use of the word thread is problematic but that is how i remember the question.

Comment: i updated the word thread with list size. maybe now this makes more sense?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution does not yield the minimum always. Consider this case:

```
total     threads
0         1 1 1 1   
2         2 1 1
2+3       3 1
2+3+4     4
```

The best solution is:

```
total     threads
0         1 1 1 1   
2         2 1 1
2+2       2 2
2+2+4     4
```

This is similar to constructing the Huffman Tree. In each step you have to sum the smallest two threads. To keep track of that, you have to insert all thread durations in a min-heap. Then in each step you take two, sum and put the result back in the heap. You have to do that until the heap have only one element.

In Java, this would be something like:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Main {
    public static int solve(int... input) {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
        for (int x : input) {
            pq.add(x);
        }

        int total = 0;
        while (pq.size() > 1) {
            Integer a = pq.poll();
            Integer b = pq.poll();
            total += a + b;
            pq.add(a + b);
        }

        return total;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solve(20, 10, 30));
        System.out.println(solve(1, 1, 1, 1));
    }
}
```